# Using page.js, is it possible to have nested data routes?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, page.js

For example, I have a route between multiple pages like login, home, contact etc. But under home I would like to create a data route for a drawer panel which would route to content within the home page. Or something like swipe-pages between tabs? Is this possible at all?

```
                <paper-tabs selected="{{selectedPage}}">
                    <paper-tab>Page 0</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab>Page 1</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab>Page 2</paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs>


                <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
                    <section data-route="home">
                        <paper-material elevation="1">                 

                            <swipe-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{selectedPage}}">
                                <swipe-page layout vertical center center-justified>1</swipe-page>
                                <swipe-page layout vertical center center-justified>2</swipe-page>
                                <swipe-page layout vertical center center-justified>3</swipe-page>
                            </swipe-pages>
                        </paper-material>


                    </section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "data route"? Is it hitting a backend api? You can do sub-routes easily like `home/sub-route`. It's the first example on https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/

Comment: I dont just mean sub-route, I will eidt my question above and show you an example @anthony